# How do you specify the only test to run with pytest k parameter?

Tags: python, pytest

I've tried the following:

python -m pytest ./subfolder -k 'test_common_fields'

This doesn't work at all. It finds nothing but this test exists in that subfolder's file of the same name 'subfolder/test_subfolder.py'

I tried entering full path: -k 'subfolder/test_subfolder.py::test_common_fields' and without "subfolder" path. Nothing.

Comment: `python -m pytest ./subfolder/test_subfolder.py -k 'test_common_fields'` does this work?

Comment: no it turns out i didn't need single quotes.

Comment: @Dexter ah, you're on windows using cmd.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu, I generally use `py.test --verbose -k testcase_1 test_xyz.py`